# How to run a ASP.net project to Xamarin Studio

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, xamarin

I developed a website using ASP.net and it works perfectly but my Manager ask me to deploy it on a Ubuntu server so i tried to run it on a Xamarin Studio then when I tried to run the project on the Xamarin Studio I get this error.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.

Hope somebody can help me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mono does not implement every bits of Microsoft's.

Try ASP.NET 5 and deploy it via Docker. Microsoft BUILD 2015 has many sessions on that and you can find on Channel 9.

Comment: This is very something new to me and I don't have any idea how to start. but thanks atleast I have a new option.

Comment: @Dave don't worry much as it is new to everyone.

Comment: Hi, How can I contact you because i don't know where to start. My project runs on ASP.net 4.0